# ImportError: No module named functions in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

How to add functions in my model?

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth
ImportError: No module named functions

    report.objects.filter(r_id=id, r_checkin_date__gte=checkin_date)
        .annotate(month=ExtractMonth('timestamp')) 
        .values('month')                          
        .annotate(count=Count('id'))                  
        .values('month', 'count')
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct version of Django that supports this import?

Comment: not available in versions older than 1.10

Comment: Yeah. import is supporting. I imported a lot library but when I am going to access something from functions that issue coming.

Comment: I need group by months. Is it possible to do another way ?

Answer (score 0):

What version on Django are you using:

`from django.db.models.functions.datetime import TruncMonth`
 is only available in version 1.10 and dev

here is source code [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/db/models/functions/datetime/)